# Double slash (//) as XML comment

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, w3c

I was a bit surprised that using double slash as comments seems to be valid XML.

The following parses correctly with Python and `xml.etree.ElementTree` and under `xmllint --format`:

```
<root>
    <child1>text1</child1>
    <child2></child2> //this is a valid comment
    <child3></child3>
</root>
```

I first thought that this could be seen as text node for root element, but trying it on python3 proved me wrong:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> r=ET.parse("test.xml").getroot()
>>> r.text
'\n    '
>>> child2=r[1]
>>> child2.text
>>> ET.tostring(child2)
b'<child2 /> //this is a valid comment\n    '
```

Can someone point me to the spec where this is allowed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### XML Explanation

No, [**comments**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-comment) can **only** be `<!-- comment -->` in XML.  You're seeing `//this is a valid comment` as ***text***, which is allowed between elements in [**mixed content**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content).  You could just as easily have left out the `//`.

### Python ElementTree Explanation

`ET.tostring(e)` is returning `e.tail` (the text appearing after `e`) as part of its string representation of `e`.  This can be confusing as most would expect `ET.tostring(e)` to return strictly some string value of the element of `e` and not include its text node sibling.  But, since `e.tail` is part of ET's element data structure, I suppose ET's designers felt justified in including `e.tail` too.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a valid comment but rather a text-node of the `<root>` element.

```
<child2></child2> //this is a valid comment
```

would be seen as

> ...element-node("child2"), text-node(" //this is a valid comment\n"), element-node("child3")...

What you want is

```
<child2></child2> <!-- this is a valid comment -->
```

which would translate to a *real* XML-comment-node

> ...element-node("child2"), comment-node(" //this is a valid comment"), element-node("child3")...

(I omitted empty text-nodes for simplicity.)

Comment: No it's not seen as a text node under root. Try it on python:
it's seen part of child2 node

Comment: Try `xmllint --sax a.xml`. Its result shows that the characters occur after the `child2` element.

Comment: interesting! So if it is characters not belonging to child2, why does ET.tostring(child2) prints them ? would it be a problem in xml.etree ?

Comment: @navidof: It's because `ET.tostring(child2)` is returning `child2.tail` as part of its string representation of `child2`.  This is admittedly confusing, but it does not mean that that `e.tail` is a child of `child2`.   See [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44978161/290085) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--This is a valid comment-->
```

You need to put the comment this way. Same way comments are formed in HTML.

Comment: Well I know that one, I want to know why the other form also works.
Couldn't find anything in the xml spec related to that. But I may have looked at the wrong place.

Comment: No other form should work. There is CDATA, but it's different.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean. The fact that Python parses it, doesn't mean it's correct as a comment, it is treated as text under the root node, as zx485 points out.

Comment: my tests shows the contrary. I think python respects the standard, it wouldn't parse invalid xml. So this for some reason is valid xml

Comment: it's not invalid XML, it's just not a comment. //this is a valid comment, is not a comment it's text.